# What is a good tool to zip large dataset w/ encryption?

Tags: encryption, zip

WinZip bombed on us while trying to zip a large dataset, and 7zip doesn't have the Encryption feature. Is there a better tool out there?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you are using an up to date version of 7zip?  The version I have supports AES-256 encryption....  I right click a file, select "Add to archive..." and one of the options is Encryption.

Comment: 7Zip has better encryption than a standard zip. AES-256 is much better than the standard zip encryption. 7z files are not compatible with winzip or other programs, but you can use the SFX option to create a self extracting zip. Also it also has great scripting capabilities: http://codeblog.theg2.net/2010/02/powershell-7-zip-amazon-s3-upload.html

Answer (score 2):

Use 7zip to compress the data, and use a program like pgp/gpg to do the encryption of the compressed data.

Answer (score 0):

[RAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAR) is the answer.

- Support for archive files larger than 9 GB.
- Support for Unicode names.
- Encryption of both file data and file headers.
- Split archive support
- Comparable compression to 7z and .zip formats.
- Error recovery

Answer (score 0):

Try [IZArc](http://www.izarc.org/). It free and supports encrypting files using Rijandael - AES (256-bits).